# How to use guard inside of a loop?

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to get the desired result using one less loop?

```
    .loop(2);

    .loop (@n, @j: @n) when (@j >= 0) {
        .loop(@j, @j - 1/2);
        @i: floor(@j);            // integer part
        @f: floor(mod(@j, 1)*10); // fractional part
        .height-@{i}-@{f} {
            height: 1% * @j;
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
.height-0-0 {
  height: 0%;
}
.height-0-5 {
  height: 0.5%;
}
.height-1-0 {
  height: 1%;
}
```

How to get such a result (Do not display second 0)?

```
.height-0 {
  height: 0%;
}
.height-0-5 {
  height: 0.5%;
}
.height-1 {
  height: 1%;
}

height-1-5
height-2
```

e.t.c.

Comment: I believe you just need another guard inside of the loop to print the class without the -0 if f is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need some guards(can be used as if statements) inside of your loop, here are docs

http://lesscss.org/features/#css-guards-feature

Here is a pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/deGWKR

```
.loop(2);

.loop (@n, @j: @n) when (@j >= 0) {
  .loop(@j, @j - 1/2);
  @i: floor(@j); // integer part
  @f: floor(mod(@j, 1)*10); // fractional part

  .height-@{i}-@{f} when (@f > 0) {
    height: 1% * @j;
    color: red;
  }

  .height-@{i} when (@f = 0) {
    height: 1% * @j;
    color: brown;
  }
}
```

This generates

```
.height-0 {
  height: 0%;
  color: green;
}
.height-0-5 {
  height: 0.5%;
  color: red;
}
.height-1 {
  height: 1%;
  color: green;
}
.height-1-5 {
  height: 1.5%;
  color: red;
}
.height-2 {
  height: 2%;
  color: green;
}
```

`.height-@{i}-@{f} when (@f > 0) {...}` says generate this class only if `f` is bigger than 0

`.height-@{i} when (@f = 0) {...}` says generate this class only if `f` equals 0

Comment: Thank you for your help Huangism. Now I understand. 
Thank you very much for the links to the documentation.